# Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length when trying to split token

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

hello i  have this line of code am trying to split the tokens gotten from the http readerGetResponse stream,

whle breaking the code it shows this error "Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length when trying to split token"

```
Dim tokens As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        Dim url As String = String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}", app_id, "http://localhost:28782/webform2.aspx", scope, Me.Request("code").ToString(), app_secret)
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)


        Using response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(Request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim vals As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            For Each token As String In vals.Split("&"c)
                **tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")), token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1))**
            Next
        End Using
        Dim access_token As String = tokens("access_token")
        Context.Session("AccessToken") = access_token
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:28782/allproducts.aspx")
```

where i highlighted is where the error is. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To check that the = is present & to handle the length, such that it handles it if its in the first position as mentioned in the comments of the other answer, try something like:

```
For Each token As String In vals.Split("&"c)
    dim i as integer = token.IndexOf("=")
    if (i <> -1) Then
        dim newLength as integer = token.length - i
        if newLength > 0 then
           newLength -= 1
        end if
        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, i), token.Substring(i + 1, newLength))**
     end if
Next
```